# what is the right sentence to input on the letter

Tags: grammar

Help me to construct a question?

Is my sentence right if a say, "Imposing of penalty is applicable?"

I was the one asking, if I said that? Am I right or wrong?

If I'm wrong, Could you help me how can I ask properly regarding imposing of penalty?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is a statement, not a question. The question would be

> Is imposing of penalty applicable?

But you do better to use a noun instead of a gerund:

> Is the imposition of a penalty applicable?

It is not clear what you mean, perhaps the context makes it clear.  It is possible that what you actually want to say is something like

> Will a penalty be imposed?